# conda install in alpine image

Tags: docker, alpine-linux

I am tying to install `conda` in an `alpine` image and getting the below error which indicates that the `exe` is missing from the download. I was reading that the `conda` install is linked to `glibc` and that isn't available in `alpine`. I am using the official build with `python 3.8`, but I am missing something. Thank you :).

```
miniconda.sh: line 412: /opt/conda/conda.exe: No such file or directory
miniconda.sh: line 414: /opt/conda/conda.exe: No such file or directory
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM alpine:3.12.3

ENV CONDA_VERSION=py38_4.9.2

RUN apk add --no-cache --virtual build_deps bash && \

    wget --quiet https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-${CONDA_VERSION}-Linux-x86_64.sh -O miniconda.$
    bash miniconda.sh -b -p /opt/conda && \
    echo "export PATH=opt/conda/bin:${PATH}" >> /root/.bashrc && \
    rm -f miniconda.sh && \
    /opt/conda/bin/conda clean -afy
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if there are other solutions, but `continuumio/miniconda3:4.7.12-alpine` as the base image seems to be the answer. The image is on `docker hub`. Thank you :).